# jQuery XML parsing error

Tags: jquery, xml

I am trying to write a simple RSS parser for my website. Although I am getting error

> XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{85891b5c-0ab8-4b89-92ba-bdef3e044891} Line Number 1, Column 1:

What does this error mean?

```
$(function () {

    var rssUrl = "http://www.guardian.co.uk/energy-saving-trust/rss";
    $.get(rssUrl, function(data) {
        var $xml = $(data);
        $xml.find("item").each(function() {
            var $this = $(this),
            item = {
                title: $this.find("title").text(),
                link: $this.find("link").text(),
                description: $this.find("description").text(),
                pubDate: $this.find("pubDate").text(),
                author: $this.find("author").text()
            }
            alert('got here');   
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that looks like a cross domain call do you have a pluggin or something to allow for that?

EDIT! leaving some examples of ways to read rss crossdomain

have your server proxy the content

or use a libary and service like

1. https://developers.google.com/feed/
2. http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/
3. http://zazar.net/developers/jquery/zrssfeed

Comment: Yes, I want to embed the Guardian RSS feed into my website. I didn't realise I needed to use a plugin if it wasn't on the same domain

Comment: theres ways to get rss feeds cross domain. OBS! by pluggin i mean jquery plugin not a browser one

Comment: Yes of course managed to get it working using http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zrssfeed/